# Is there a way to remove the uniform from the Spy without "being spotted"?

Tags: commandos

I'm replaying the classic Commandos: Beyond the Call of Duty.

While playing the game, on the second tutorial mission, on the very beginning, you can use the Spy to stun a soldier and get his uniform. With this done, you can get to where the other ally soldiers are, but when using a uniform, the Spy can't crouch or pass the obstacle course and go to where the other soldiers are.

I want to remove the disguise from the Spy to allow him to crouch and deal with the enemies behind the obstacle course non-lethally, but there seems to be no way to do it, as there's no icon or key shortcut that I know of to do it and I haven't found anything on the Internet.

The only way I know to remove the disguise is by being detected by enemies, which automatically removes the disguise, but I don't want to be detected by enemies, of course.

Comment: It's been like 15 years since I played this so I can't remember the interface exactly but as far as I remember you could remove it. Maybe you can't remove because "tutorial mode"?

Comment: I'm playing the game now and there doesn't seem to be any option to do that. The only thing you can do is to change to another uniform or as you said be detected by the enemies